# DataLossError: Unable to open table file error in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, fraud-prevention

i have been studying for a while this kaggle link [Predicting Fraud with TensorFlow](https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/predicting-fraud-with-tensorflow)

. The dataset releated to fraud . He commented on line 33 , but when i try to rewrite codes that about saving/checkpointing it always gives an error.

```
DataLossError: Unable to open table file C:\Users\Mert\best_model.ckpt: Data loss: file is too short to be an sstable: perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
 [[Node: save_5/RestoreV2_51 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save_5/Const_0_0, save_5/RestoreV2_51/tensor_names, save_5/RestoreV2_51/shape_and_slices)]]
```

at first i created empty file right location that called best_model . i have taken this error after i converted empty best_model.txt file to best_model.ckpt .

Could you help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Empty files are not valid tensorflow checkpoint files. Try saving a checkpoint by training a model first.